# method to keep the code DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project creation form which creates a new project where in I have the parameters come as an array for these 3 attributes, which I need to convert to a string with a ',' using the join method, and I am doing the following:

```
@project.trackers = @project.trackers.join(',') if !@project.trackers.nil?
@project.modules = @project.modules.join(',') if !@project.modules.nil?
@project.custom_fields = @project.custom_fields.join(',') if !@project.custom_fields.nil?
@project.repository = @project.repository.join(',') if !@project.repository.nil?
```

As I am using the same logic for all the variables I would like to create a method which will pass some arguments and do this in one line.

Any good suggestions will be very helpful.

Tried:

```
array = ['trackers','modules','custom_fields','repository']
joiner(array) #method call

    def joiner(args)
        args.each do |param|
          if !param.nil?
            @project.param = @project.param.join(',')  
            # Stuck how to convert param string
          end  
        end  
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaprogramming to the rescue:

```
%w(trackers modules custom_fields repository).each do |field| 
  @project.send("#{field}=", @project.send(field.to_sym).join(',')) if @project.send(field.to_sym)
end
```

**Update**

There is a [very good book](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby-2) if you like to solve this type of problems like a pro.

Comment: Thanks, there is a minor typo in unless @project.send(field.to_sym)).nil? should be unless @project.send(field.to_sym).nil?

Comment: `unless @project.send(field.to_sym)).nil?` can be `if @project.send(field.to_sym))`

Comment: Updated. Sorry for small mistakes. Point stays.

Answer (score 2):

```
%w[trackers modules custom_fields repository].each do
  |param|
  unless (a = @project.send(param)).nil?
    @project.send("#{param}=", a.join(","))
  end
end
```

If you can live with the values being an empty string instead of `nil`, then

```
%w[trackers modules custom_fields repository]
.each{|param| @project.send("#{param}=", @project.send(param).to_a.join(","))}
```